# How to receive broadcasts in ServiceTestCase<MyService>?

Tags: java, android, testing

I'm stuck with this issue.

**Here is the code of my service:**

```
public class APIService extends IntentService {

    public static final String MY_SERVICE = "com.approject.myproject.APIService";
    private HttpClient httpClient = null;
    private ArrayList<AbbrRecord> results = null;

/*Constructor*/
public APIService(){
    super("APIService");  
}

/*Process created.*/
/*Intialize HttpClient.*/
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
}

/*HandleIntent from Activities*/
@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent i){
    results = null;
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet("http://www.someurl.com" +    i.getStringExtra("search_request")); //getData().toString()
    try{
        InputStream instream = null;
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null){
            instream = entity.getContent();
        }
        InputSource input_source = new InputSource(instream);
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try{
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xml_reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            DataParser content_handler = new DataParser();
            xml_reader.setContentHandler(content_handler);
            xml_reader.setErrorHandler(content_handler);
            xml_reader.parse(input_source);
            results = content_handler.pullDataOut();
        }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SAXException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(results == null){
        if( i.getIntExtra("sender", -1) == 0){
            Intent it = new Intent("DATA_WAS_NOT_RETRIEVED"); 
            sendBroadcast(it);
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "DATA_WAS_NOT_RETRIEVED BROADCAST WAS SENT FOR MAIN");
        } else {
            Intent it = new Intent("DATA_WAS_NOT_RETRIEVED_RESULTS"); 
            sendBroadcast(it);
        }
    } else {
        if(i.getIntExtra("sender", -1) == 0){
            Intent it = new Intent("RETRIEVE_DATA_MAIN"); 
            it.putExtra("search_results", results);
            sendBroadcast(it);
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "DATA_RETRIEVED BROADCAST WAS SENT FOR MAIN");
        } else {
            Intent it = new Intent("RETRIEVE_DATA_RESULTS");
            it.putExtra("search_results", results);
            sendBroadcast(it);
        }
    }
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Intent was handled.");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d( getClass().getSimpleName(), "APIService is destroyed");
}
}
```

**APIServiceTest.java**

```
public class APIServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<APIService>{

private BroadcastReceiver receiver1 = null;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver2 = null;
private ArrayList<AbbrRecord> results = null;

public APIServiceTest(){
    super(APIService.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
    receiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){ 
            ArrayList<AbbrRecord> results = (ArrayList)intent.getSerializableExtra("search_results");
        }
    };
    receiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            ArrayList<AbbrRecord> results = (ArrayList)intent.getSerializableExtra("search_results");
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(); 
    filter1.addAction("RETRIEVE_DATA_MAIN");
    getSystemContext().registerReceiver(receiver1, filter1);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();
    filter2.addAction("DATA_WAS_NOT_RETRIEVED");
    getSystemContext().registerReceiver(receiver2, filter2);
}

public void testMakeRequest() throws InterruptedException{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("search_request", "asap");
    i.putExtra("sender", 0);
    i.setClassName("com.approject.myproject", "com.approject.myproject.APIService"); 
    getSystemContext().startService(i);
    assertFalse(results == null); 
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
    super.tearDown();
    if(receiver1 != null && receiver2 != null){
        getSystemContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver1);
        getSystemContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver2);
    }
}
}
```

I already tried using MockApplication, MockContext classes.

**Command line output**: 
com.approject.APIServiceTest:

```
Failure in testMakeRequest:

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError

at com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest.testMakeRequest(APIServiceTest.java:71)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)

at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)

at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)

..

Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=.F..

Time: 10.239
FAILURES!!!

Tests run: 3,  Failures: 1,  Errors: 0
```

**Log**:

```
02-07 19:54:13.358: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(239): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime   START<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
02-07 19:54:13.358: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(239): CheckJNI is ON
02-07 19:54:13.568: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(239): --- registering native functions ---
02-07 19:54:13.888: DEBUG/ddm-heap(239): Got feature list request
02-07 19:54:14.208: DEBUG/ActivityManager(59): Uninstalling process    com.approject.myproject
02-07 19:54:14.238: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.approject.myproject for  added application com.approject.myproject: pid=245 uid=10029 gids={3003, 1015}
02-07 19:54:14.368: DEBUG/ddm-heap(245): Got feature list request
02-07 19:54:14.588: INFO/TestRunner(245): started: testMakeRequest(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:15.778: DEBUG/dalvikvm(245): GC freed 3273 objects / 241584 bytes in 83ms
02-07 19:54:17.398: DEBUG/APIService(245): DATA_RETRIEVED BROADCAST WAS SENT FOR MAIN
02-07 19:54:17.398: DEBUG/APIService(245): Intent was handled.
02-07 19:54:17.518: DEBUG/dalvikvm(245): GC freed 5615 objects / 327224 bytes in 62ms
02-07 19:54:17.888: DEBUG/APIService(245): APIService is destroyed
02-07 19:54:24.650: INFO/TestRunner(245): failed: testMakeRequest(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.650: INFO/TestRunner(245): ----- begin exception -----
02-07 19:54:24.679: INFO/TestRunner(245): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
02-07 19:54:24.679: INFO/TestRunner(245):     at  junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
02-07 19:54:24.679: INFO/TestRunner(245):     at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
02-07 19:54:24.679: INFO/TestRunner(245):     at junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:34)
02-07 19:54:24.679: INFO/TestRunner(245):     at junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:41)
02-07 19:54:24.679: INFO/TestRunner(245):     at com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest.testMakeRequest(APIServiceTest.java:71)...
02-07 19:54:24.689: INFO/TestRunner(245): ----- end exception -----
02-07 19:54:24.729: INFO/TestRunner(245): finished: testMakeRequest(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.749: INFO/TestRunner(245): started: testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.799: INFO/TestRunner(245): finished: testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.799: INFO/TestRunner(245): passed: testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.809: INFO/TestRunner(245): started: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.829: INFO/TestRunner(245): finished: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.829: INFO/TestRunner(245): passed: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.approject.myproject.APIServiceTest)
02-07 19:54:24.859: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(239): Shutting down VM
02-07 19:54:24.859: DEBUG/dalvikvm(239): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
02-07 19:54:24.869: DEBUG/ActivityManager(59): Uninstalling process com.approject.myproject
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: in your receivers you are updating two separate local variables: ArrayList<AbbrRecord> results; But your global variable "results" is always NULL;

Comment: Thank you Alex. I've got to check my eyes.